# Alien invasion novel where black discs fall throughout a city and prick everyone giving them "flu"

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship, alien-invasion

While in secondary school I read this alien invasion novel (my favorite novel) but it had no front page so I had no way of telling the name so I just named it "Invasion".

Brief description: There was a meteor and these black discs fell throughout the city and anyone that tried picking them up, a sharp needle like point pricks them but it’s only visible when you try to open it.

The whole city gradually got pricked and they had an epidemic of flu, or at least they thought it was just the flu, but after a few days, I think 3-5, they’d get better and start acting weird.

The host was, in his words, trying to better Earth, so he got an estate and placed his space ship there.
There were 5 survivors.

It didn't have a last page so I never knew how it ended.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Indeed, welcome. Your details were good enough to find your work. :) Stick around! We're fun people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funnily enough, this looks to indeed be Robin Cook's *[Invasion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NAXVNBE)*.

> To anyone glancing upwards at the night sky, it would have seemed like a brilliant shooting star… but moments later electronic equipment of every kind began to spark and explode throughout the city.
>
> The following morning, college student Beau Stark is the first to pick up one of the countless strange black discs scattered far and wide. After an initial sharp pain like a bee-sting, he becomes gradually ‘infested’. His flu-like symptoms signify the revival of an alien virus implanted millions of years in mankind’s genetic code – and since then lying dormant until the unwitting hosts are sufficiently developed to aid its relentless progress.
>
> Meanwhile, all over the nation, other human beings and animals succumb to the same virus and start to behave bizarrely and symbiotically – as if controlled by some outside influence.
>
> As Beau assumes leadership of this growing band of the ‘infested’, his college friends quickly realize that something truly horrifying is happening around them. Desperately struggling to piece together the puzzle, they soon become hunted refugees in a desperate quest to save humanity – before the Gateway opens.

I found it by searching for *alien invasion novel "black discs"*

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_(Cook_novel)) has a description of the plot. If you don't feel like tracking it down, it looks like the ending is that

> The group escapes the facility and storms the mansion, smashing the gateway with a car. Beau is too far gone to be cured and tells them to run as the destruction of the gateway would cause dispersion[clarification needed]. He dies and the mansion is destroyed but they are able to spread the cure and the invasion is halted.